# Unity GetComponent(GUIText) bug?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, gameobject

I have an issue with the GetComponent(GUIText) the error i get is

There is no 'GUIText' attached to the "#######COUNTER(Clone)" game object, but a script is trying to access it.

Here is my code:

```
var UItecxt = GameObject.Find("#######COUNTER(Clone)");
var txtconvert = UItecxt.GetComponent(GUIText);
print(txtconvert);
txtconvert.text = counternumb.ToString();
```

I HAVE a GUIText on my clone! What is the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that there is **no GameObject named** `"#######COUNTER(Clone)"` cloned in the scene. Run my code below and you will notice.

```
var UItecxt = GameObject.Find("#######COUNTER(Clone)");
var txtconvert : GUIText;

if(UItecxt != null)
   txtconvert = UItecxt.GetComponent(GUIText);

else
  Debug.Log("There was no GameObject with the name '#######COUNTER(Clone)' in the scene");
```

To fix it just make sure you do have a `GameObject` with that name.

Comment: Actually there is a Gameobject named that and it does find it. But yet again i get the error "There is no 'GUIText' attached to the "COUNTER" game object, but a script is trying to access it."

Comment: Code: function Update () {
var UIttecxt = GameObject.FindWithTag("COUNTER");
var txttconvert : GUIText;
print(UIttecxt);
if(UIttecxt != null){
txttconvert = UIttecxt.GetComponent(GUIText);
txttconvert.text = counternumb.ToString();
}
else {
Debug.Log("There was no GameObject with the name 'COUNTER' in the scene");
}

Comment: `GetComponent()` either finds the `Component` or it doesn't, there is no magic. So you need to make sure it is really attached to your `Counter`

Comment: For some reason when i dont put (Clone) in front of the name, i.e. COUNTER(Clone) --> COUNTER it doesn't work. Why can i not GameObject.Find my Instantiated UI object?

Comment: You are finding the object by `Tag` now. If you want to Find by name then you need the exact name `COUNTER(Clone)` or `COUNTER` whatever the name happens to be. Also if you use a Tag make sure the tag name is correct.

Comment: Okay, so I tryed a different approach and put a script ON the text itself and guess what? It says there is no GUIText on the GUIText! Why can i not get the TextComponent??? I used this to get the text ON the GUIText : var text = gameObject.GetComponent(GUIText);

Comment: And i tried to put the same script on parent and it still did not work

Comment: Something weird is happening on your end. I am able to use it perfectly.

Comment: hmmmm... are you Instantiating your object? Can you tell me exactly what your doing?

Comment: Yes I instantiate from a prefab. Then I look for the name of the object. Then I grab the GUIText component.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not detail enough to determine the problem.

Still, i assumed the gameobject that you mentioned should be a prefab that you instantiated.

Where you put or attach the sciprt? Make sure it is attached to the prefab that you instantiated.

Also, you can try use direct reference the component instead of using gameobject.Find.
It is easier for you to drag and drop element at the inspector.

Comment: Yes it is an instantiated Gameobject but I do not want to attach this script to the object, all im asking is why its saying that there is no GUI text attached.

Comment: This is the code i'm having trouble with: var txtconvert = UItecxt.GetComponent(GUIText);

Comment: are you sure UItext had found the gameobject you want?

Comment: or you may want to use gameobject.FindWithTag, this way it is more accurate and fast by just search through the tags and not all the gameobject.